# Function Returning undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined

Working on a project, I have this issue where my array "slicetable" returns undefined every time, and I do not know how to solve this problem. I have a function that generates an array of likelihoods for cryptographic key lengths - I then need to split the text into individual strings of n-th keys, up to the length of the "key". I've worked for the last 4 hours on this problem, and don't know where to begin. If anyone could recommend a good strategy for tackling problems like this, as well as helping me out on this one, that would be great - I'm still quite new to all of this.

```
function vigenerekey(text, max) {
    // Standardize the text
    text = text.split(" ").join("").toUpperCase();
    // Obtain our list of key length probabilities
    var probabilities = vigenerekeylength(text, max);
    // Extend the Math.max to arrays
    Array.max = function(array){
        return Math.max.apply(Math, array);
    };

    // Find the position of the most probable key length
    for (var d = 0; d <=12; d++) {
        if (probabilities[d] === probabilities.max) {
            return;
        }
    }
    // Slice the text into [d] parts (the length of the key)
    var slicetable = ['','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''];
    var chiresults = [];
    for (var e = 0; e <= d; e++){
        for (f = 0; f <= text.length; f++) {
            if (f % e === 0) {
                slicetable[e] += text.charAt(f);        
            }
        }
    return slicetable;
    }

}
```

Comment: Almost certainly the problem is in the `if (probabilities[d] === probabilities.max) {return;}` block, but could you supply some sample inputs and expected outputs?  A quick read of this does not make it clear what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Maybe it's returning from the inside of that "probabilities" loop, which will always result in it the return value being `undefined`.

Comment: Also, it's probably a bad idea to reassign `Array.max` on every call to this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't you mean this: (break instead of return)

```
// Find the position of the most probable key length 
for (var d = 0; d <=12; d++) { 
    if (probabilities[d] === probabilities.max) { 
        break;
    } 
}
```

Comment: I didn't realize that there was a part of Javascript called "break;" Thanks, and sorry for my ineptness.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the return statement inside your for-loop. You want to put

```
break;
```

instead of

```
return;
```

---

I had a typo in my first answer (I was the first to post an answer), and a moderator deleted it. I fixed the typo, but it says I can't undelete it... So I'll try again.

Comment: You were the first to answer, but the answer was wrong (replace return with continu). I think that's why it was removed.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly why. After I saw that it was removed I realized I wrote continue instead of break. Thanks for the upvote!

Comment: @11101101b Yeah, it says deleted by casperOne